# How to fetch BigQuery data into a springboot application?

Tags: spring-boot, google-bigquery, spring-data-jpa

I have a use case wherein I need to fetch data from GCP BigQuery database into my Springboot application and subsequently perform some operations on it. I'm unable to understand how to go about doing it. For example, how the application properties need to be configured for using BQ database, etc, nor was I able to find any good resource for the same.

Request you all to kindly guide me a bit on this. Would be great even if you could point me to a relevant resource!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there are no examples on Spring Cloud documentation. However there is nice sample on [spring-cloud-gcp github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/main/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery-sample).

There is small tutorial how to run it, so I think this will be good starting point.